# How would I center text both vertically and horizontally in a cell in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

For some reason, my text doesn't center properly, and is instead offset by a small amount in the vertical direction.

This is the code for this table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=120pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\thead{Temperature \\ (\degree\si{C} $\pm$ 0.1 \degree\si{C})}} & \multicolumn{10}{ c |}{\thead{Volume of \chemfig{MgCl_2} solution added \\ (\si{cm^3} $\pm$ 0.05 \si{cm^3})}} \\ \cline{2-11}
    & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{\thead{Trial 1}}  & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{\thead{Trial 2}}  & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{\thead{Trial 3}} & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{\thead{Trial 4}}  & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{\thead{Trial 5}} \\ \cline{2-11}
    & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} \\ \hline

    \thead{20} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{35} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{50} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{65} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{80} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This code outputs this table:
[image: Table]

As you can see, the first cell (Temperature (°C ± 0.1 °C)) is slightly off center in the vertical direction. I am making use of the `makecell` package to format the text. How should I change it so that it is properly centered?

Comment: Welcome into the community of the users of TeX. Please, can you put a complete code adding the packages? It is very important and thank you very much.

Comment: I have edited it so that now it compiles --- there was a typo (`makecells` instead of `makecell`) and missing `begin`/`end` document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shift `multirow` cell slightly down, for example with use decimal number of text lines in spanned rows:

```
\multirow{4.4}{*}{\thead{Temperature\\ ($\si{\celsius} \pm\SI{0.1}{\celsius}$)}}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=120pt}

%\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c |}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
\multirow{4.4}{*}{\thead{Temperature\\ ($\si{\celsius} \pm\SI{0.1}{\celsius}$)}} 
    &   \mcc[10]{%
        \thead{Volume of \chemfig{MgCl_2} solution added \\ 
               ($\si{\per\centi\metre\cubed} \pm\SI{0.05}{\per\centi\metre\cubed}$)}} \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & \mcc[2]{\thead{Trial 1}}  
        & \mcc[2]{\thead{Trial 2}}  
            & \mcc[2]{\thead{Trial 3}} 
                & \mcc[2]{\thead{Trial 4}}  
                    & \mcc[2]{\thead{Trial 5}} \\ 
    \cline{2-11}
    & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} 
    & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} & \thead{Start} & \thead{End} \\
    \hline

    \thead{20} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{35} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{50} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{65} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \thead{80} & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Complete MWE, with more correct use of `siunitx` units and added new command for `\multicolumn` cells (bot are off-topic, of course :-) )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `\multirow`, you have to provide the number of lines of text (which is not exactly the number of rows of the tabular).

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` you have a command `\Block` and, for that command, you give in as argument the numbers of **rows** of the tabular and the content is drawn mathematically at the center of the rectangle of merged cells (`\Block` may be used to merge cells vertically but also horizontally).

In your case, the use of `{NiceTabular}` has also the avantage of providing a key `hvlines` which draws all the rules excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`). That's what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\geometry{margin=120pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{11}{c}}[hvlines]
    \Block{3-1}{Temperature \\ (\degree\si{C} $\pm$ 0.1 \degree\si{C})} & \Block{1-10}{Volume of \chemfig{MgCl_2} solution added \\ (\si{cm^3} $\pm$ 0.05 \si{cm^3})} \\ 
    & \Block{1-2}{Trial 1}&  & \Block{1-2}{Trial 2}&  & \Block{1-2}{Trial 3}& & \Block{1-2}{Trial 4}&  & \Block{1-2}{Trial 5} \\ 
    & Start & End & Start & End & Start & End & Start & End & Start & End \\ 
    20 \\ 
    35 \\ 
    50 \\ 
    65 \\ 
    80 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]